# Confused with the callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, request

I have got a node js program as below.

```
msg = "Generate a number......";
sessionAttributes = {};
console.log("Session arreubs are :" + sessionAttributes);
console.log("end of flow");
callback(close(intentRequest.sessionAttributes, "Fulfilled", buildMessage(msg)));
```

here is my close callback

```
function close(sessionAttributes, fulfillmentState, message) {
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: "Close",
            fulfillmentState,
            message,
        },
    };
}
```

when I run this, I get the output as `Generate a number......`. But now I need to integrate this with an API call. and the updated code is as below.

```
var service = require("./service.js");
service.createIncident(enterpriseID, shortDesc,
    function (incidentNo) {
        if (incidentNo) {
            console.log("Index.js ServiceNow Incident:" + incidentNo);
            msg = "Thank you! Your " + TicketType + " Number is " + incidentNo;
            console.log("end of flow");
            callback(close(intentRequest.sessionAttributes, "Fulfilled", buildMessage(msg)));

        } else {
            console.log("Index.js ServiceNow Incident:" + incidentNo);
            msg = "Err";
            console.log("end of flow");
            callback(close(intentRequest.sessionAttributes, "Fulfilled", buildMessage(msg)));

        }
    });
console.log("process is done");
```

my **service.js**

```
var request = require("request");
var servicenow = require("./configfile.json");

var snowURL = servicenow.url;
var snowUsername = servicenow.username;
var snowPassword = servicenow.password;
var ticketNo = "00000";

console.log("Service Now URL:" + snowURL + " Username:" + snowUsername + " Password:" + snowPassword);

module.exports.createIncident = function (caller_id, short_description, callback) {
    var snowdetails = {
        uri: snowURL,
        method: "POST",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "auth": {
            "username": snowUsername,
            "password": snowPassword
        }
    };
    request(snowdetails, function (error, resp, body) {
        console.log("Status code " + resp.statusCode);
        if (!error && (resp.statusCode == 200 || resp.statusCode == 201)) {
            if (body) {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                ticketNo = data.result.number;
                console.log("Service Now Incident No:" + ticketNo);
                callback(ticketNo);
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("I am unable to authenticate you. please disable the skill and re link your account");
                callback("I am unable to authenticate you. please disable the skill and re link your account");

            }
        } else {
            console.log(error);
            callback(error);

        }
    });
};
```

Here when I run this, I get the output as

```
process is done
Service Now Incident No:INC0010035
Index.js ServiceNow Incident:INC0010035
Thank you! Your incident Number is INC0010035
```

and in my window, earlier, when there was no callback, it used to print the `msg` content, i.e. `Generating ticket......`, but now it is not printing anything.

Where  am I going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: inside `createIncident` function you are calling `callback(close(in ...`. You did declare callback nowhere

Comment: I declared it above, updated my question

Comment: Where are you trying to display the `msg` content?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT, I'm displaying it in my AWS console

Comment: The only thing I am seeing is that `callback` in `createIncident` is `undefined` so your message is not updated.

Comment: Ohk, Can you please help me create it? One quick question, why am I able to print the value in console.log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153118/discussion-between-user3872094-and-gregory-neut).